# Difference between Dutch National Flag problem and sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

I'm reading the [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) and I don't get it: why is this different from a simple sorting problem?

I mean: if we assign 0 to the red color, 1 to white and 2 to blue and do a standard quicksort or whatever.. why should I not get the right answer?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dutch National Flag Problem is just a special case of the more general sorting problem where the only permissible elements are 0, 1, and 2. You can absolutely solve it using a standard sorting algorithm.

The problem is interesting in of itself partially for historical reasons but largely because it's challenging to find solutions that are stable, time-efficient (O(n)), and space-efficient (O(1)). It's easy to get solutions with two of these three properties, but getting all three is (I believe) an open problem. It's also interesting as a venue for developing algorithms for quick sort and partitioning with duplicate keys; you can think of 0, 1, and 2 as less than the pivot, equal to the pivot, and greater than the pivot and you basically have quick sort with repeated elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To me, what is interesting is that there is an in-place O(n) solution. (True, it is not stable. But in-place O(n) is not available for "standard sorting")

Comment: @gen-y-s Sorry, I should have made my answer clearer. In my second paragraph, I was hoping to communicate that out of O(n)-time, O(1)-space, and stable, we have algorithms for any two of the three properties but not all three simultaneously. I'll go update the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: You still seem to miss the specific point of this problem being suitable for non-comaprison sort because of the small number of possible keys. That's why "standard" sorting algorithms like quicksort are irrelevant for this problem (nor is "developing" algorithms for partitioning relevant).

Comment: @gen-y-s Oh, I'm well aware of that. I assumed that was sufficiently obvious from the problem statement. :-)

Comment: So why did you say "You can absolutely solve it using a standard sorting algorithm" ???  And "The problem is interesting ... largely because it's challenging to find solutions that are stable, time-efficient and space-efficient" which is a completely generic phrase that can be said about any problem (actually this one is not really that challenging) and doesn't mention the main point about non-comparison sort algorithms ??? Cleary the person asking this question didn't know about non-comparison sorting, and what makes this problem different than regular sorting related problems.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem the range of values of items to be sorted is small. In such cases it's possible to use non-comparison sort (eg, such as counting sort) to sort the array. Non comparison sort algorithms can sort in O(n) that is, faster than regular comparison sort algorithms such as quicksort.